# PHP sort numbers in a string by value

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

I found lots of answers relating to arrays but they don't seem to be working with my situation.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$xyz="2,8,3";

sort($xyz, SORT_NUMERIC);
echo $xyz;

?>
```

This gives me:

> Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /string.php on line 6

```
2,8,3
```

I want to sort the numbers largest first. So the desired echo would be:

```
8,3,2
```

Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Because you don't have an array.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, `sort` works on an array. What you have is a string. You can turn it into an array to sort it, and then if you want to just print it out again, turn it back into a string. If you want to do anything else with it, best to leave it as an array.

```
<?php
$xyz = "2,8,3";
$arr = explode(',', $xyz);

rsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC); //Sorts in reverse order, so high to low

$xyz = implode(',', $arr);
echo $xyz;
```